# Is there $f$ such that $e^{f(z)}=z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that there is no a function $f$ holomorphic in a deleted neighborhood of $z=0$ such that $e^{f(z)}=z$ in that neighborhood.

My idea is to write $f(z)=\dots+c_{-k}z^{-k}+\dots+c_{-1}z^{-1}+c_0+c_1z+\dots$ and $e^z=1+z+z^2/2!+z^3/3!+\dots$, and then substitute the expansion of $f(z)$ for $z$ in the second series. This will give some powers of $z^{-m},\ m> 0$ in the expansion, and such function cannot be holomorphic. Is that correct?

Comment: well, but that would only show it's not holomorphic in $0$. The question asked about a deleted neighborhood of $z=0$, so not being holomorphic in 0 doesn't tell much, right? Note that this function would be the logarithm of z, so maybe look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm to see what's wrong with it, why it's not a function, and why we can't define a complex holomorphic logarithm

Comment: Which complex analysis textbook are you following?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with Taylor series "coefficientwise" is a powerful method since you have the full toolbox of formal power series at your disposal. This toolbox lets you compute each coefficient $a_n$ of a product $f\cdot g$ or a composition $f\circ g$ (if $g(0)=0$) in terms of finitely many operations. With  Laurent expansions this is no longer the case.

The example at hand can be dealt with in the following simple way: From $e^{f(z)}= z$ $\>(z\in\dot U)$ we obtain $f'(z)e^{f(z)}\equiv1$, hence $$f'(z)={1\over z}\qquad(z\in\dot U)\ .$$
If $f$ were holomorphic in $U$ then necessarily $\int_\gamma f'(z)\>dz=0$ for small circles $\gamma$ around $0$. But we all know that $\int_\gamma{1\over z}\>dz=2\pi i$ for such circles.